# Are "where can I find a dataset on x" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Some very interesting findings can occur when a new dataset is discovered or created.

Presuming someone has done some searching in obvious places, are questions like "where can I find a dataset on x" on topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"](/help/on-topic) mentions:

> Even though the boundaries are not always perfectly clear and we often accept questions that are also appropriate on other sites, here are a few guiding thoughts:
>
> ...
>
> Other relevant sites include:
>
> - [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Dataset requests)

That's right, there's another site in the network more or less *dedicated* to these kind of requests: [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about ...
>
> - where to [find any kind of open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request)

You might want to check existing questions in their [data-request] tag to see if the data you're looking for has already been found.